# Ruby gems path file on windows returns different path?

Tags: ruby, windows

I am setting up a ruby script on windows (and I'm not a windows person) but I have run into the SSL problem. So I am creating a script to copy the correct PEM file into the ssl_certs directory. However, here is the problem I am running into.

The directory I am looking for is:
C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\

But the command gem which rubygems returns:
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/**site_ruby**/2.1.0/

Is there a way to get the path to 2.1.0 without the **site_ruby**?

Or should I manually remove this from the path?

Comment: Macs uses `/` or a forward slash, windows uses back slahs

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai While in Ruby code, using a forward slash on Windows doesn't matter. Either will work fine. I doubt slashes is the OP's problem.